# Switching users on a Mac makes ledger unreadable from tezos client

Tags: ledger

Recently, switching to a different user (not through terminal) on a Mac makes my tezos baker miss endorsements and bakes. Before I had to reinstall hidapi --HEAD, I was able to hop users and tezos software would find the ledger.